# How to show only current user registration list in Node registration view?

Tags: views

I have used views for registration type and listed as table. They listed all registered details to everyone. But I need to show only current user registration list in the table using views contextual filters.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Configure contextual filter.

Select the Name field.

Checked "**Provide default value**".

Type select box select: **User ID from logged in user**.

Refer

[image]